# Python w/ Powershell Script

Tags: python, powershell

So, I am trying to write a python program that can run a PowerShell.ps1 script as Administrator. The PowerShell script just disables the built-in webcam on any device with a integrated webcam. I'm not necessarily worried about having to press yes to activate admin mode if it's not bypassable (which I don't think it is). That being said here is my python code to run the PowerShell script.

```
POWERSHELL_PATH = "powershell.exe"  # POWERSHELL EXE PATH
ps_script_path = "C:/Omni_Digital/Omni1/disWebPS"  # YOUR POWERSHELL FILE PATH


class Utility:  # SHARED CLASS TO USE IN OUR PROJECT

    @staticmethod    # STATIC METHOD DEFINITION
    def run_ftp_upload_powershell_script(script_path, *params):  # SCRIPT PATH = POWERSHELL SCRIPT PATH,  PARAM = POWERSHELL SCRIPT PARAMETERS ( IF ANY )

        commandline_options = [POWERSHELL_PATH, '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', script_path]  # ADD POWERSHELL EXE AND EXECUTION POLICY TO COMMAND VARIABLE
        for param in params:  # LOOP FOR EACH PARAMETER FROM ARRAY
            commandline_options.append("'" + param + "'")  # APPEND YOUR FOR POWERSHELL SCRIPT

        process_result = subprocess.run(commandline_options, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)  # CALL PROCESS

        print(process_result.returncode)  # PRINT RETURN CODE OF PROCESS  0 = SUCCESS, NON-ZERO = FAIL  
        print(process_result.stdout)      # PRINT STANDARD OUTPUT FROM POWERSHELL
        print(process_result.stderr)      # PRINT STANDARD ERROR FROM POWERSHELL ( IF ANY OTHERWISE ITS NULL|NONE )

        if process_result.returncode == 0:  # COMPARING RESULT
            Message = "Success !"
        else:
            Message = "Error Occurred !"

        return Message  # RETURN MESSAGE

Utility.run_ftp_upload_powershell_script(POWERSHELL_PATH, ps_script_path)
```

Here is the PowerShell program I am calling inside of the python file in order to disable the webcam. Which works and disables the webcam.

```
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId (Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName *webcam* -Class Camera -Status OK).InstanceId -Confirm:$false
```

Now my problem is how do I elevate this PowerShell script to be in admin mode when it is called. I've seen this used:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -Verb runAs
```

However, I know the **-Verb runAs** is the portion of the script that elevates it to admin mode, but all it does in my instance is open a new window in admin mode then runs the second portion of the script in the original PowerShell windows (non-admin)